# Angular not stopping at “debugger” in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio

I’m following along in a Pluralsight course about implementing Angular into MVC. In the course the instructor is putting the word “debugger;” in the angular function to stop the code and view what data is being returned.

When I try this, my Visual Studio doesn’t stop. I can set a break point in my “/api/CallController” GET() method and it will stop there. So that tells me my Angular code is working to actually call the API. I can also see data while debugging in the “/api/controller” so it should be passing that to the Angular controller.

I would like to be able to debug inside the Angular code and actually see the data. Is there something I need to turn on or a NuGet package I need in Visual Studio?

Here is my Angular Controller and it should be stopping in the function callList();

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').controller('CallController', CallController);

    function CallController($http) {
        var vm = this;
        var dataService = $http;

        vm.calls = [];  //create an array of calls.

        //add a call for testing.
        vm.call = {
            CustomerName: 'Jim Beam',
            CustomerPhone: '940-555-1212'
        };

        callList();     //call the API function to get list of calls

        function callList(){
            dataService.get("/api/Call")
            .then(function(result) { 
                vm.calls = result.data;
                debugger;
            }, 
            function (error) {
                handleException(error)
            });
        }

        function handleException(error) {
            alert(error.data.ExceptionMessage);
        }
    }
})();
```

UPDATE

Here is a screen shot from the video. You can see it's in Visual Studio, I'm assuming 2015, and he has stopped at the debugger line and is viewing the data.

[image]

Comment: Remember that Angular runs in the browser, and any debugging you want to do should happen there, not in the IDE or editor you're using.

Comment: I'll go back and watch that section of the video but I'm pretty sure the instructor was able to stop inside of Visual Studio and view the data that was returned from the Web API. It would stop where he wrote the word "debugger;" and then he hovered over the result.data and it showed the array of items returned.

Comment: Updated the original post.

Comment: I think I found the issue. I'm using Chrome to view my site through Visual Studio. It looks like you have to use Internet Explorer to work.